# Ansible overwrites which variable? Inventory parameter or extra parameters at runtime?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have a parameter `pkg` for all hosts of an envrionment specific inventory.

```
[atlanta]
host1
host2

[atlanta:vars]
ntp_server=ntp.atlanta.example.com
proxy=proxy.atlanta.example.com
pkg=123
```

Now if I use the same variable `pkg` while executing an ansible playbook ex. `ansible-playbook xyzzy.yml -e "pkg=123"` with some different value. Which one will be picked by Ansible ? The value that is associated with `pkg` at Inventory level or the one given at runtime in command ?

Answer (score 1):

Extra variable (i.e. vars given at runtime) override all other variables. Inventory variables will be overriden by extra variable given at runtime. In detail, precedence is such as:

> Here is the order of precedence from least to greatest (the last listed variables winning prioritization):
>
> - ...
> - inventory file or script group vars
> - inventory group_vars/all
> - playbook group_vars/all
> - inventory group_vars/*
> - playbook group_vars/*
> - inventory file or script host vars
> - inventory host_vars/*
> - playbook host_vars/*
> - ...
> - extra vars (always win precedence)

The doc is indeed a bit confusing. For clarification:

- `inventory file or script group vars` are variables associated to groups in your inventory files. In your case, everything under `atlanta:vars` are inventory file group vars

  ```
  [atlanta:vars]
  pkg=123
  ```
- `inventory file or script host vars` are variables associated to a specific host and would have higher precedence other `inventory file or script group vars`, for example:

  ```
  [atlanta]
  host1 pkg=override-123
  host2
  ```
- `inventory group_vars/all|*` are variables defined under **inventories** `group_vars/` folder such as `$PLAYBOOK_DIR/inventories/my-inventory/group_vars/atlanta/main.yml`
- `playbook group_vars/all|*` are variables defined under **playbook** `group_vars/` folder such as `$PLAYBOOK_DIR/group_vars/atlanta/main.yml`
- `inventory host_vars/*` are variables under **inventories** `host_vars/` folder such as `$PLAYBOOK_DIR/inventories/my-inventory/host_vars/somehostname.yml`
- `playbook host_vars/*` are variables under **playbook** `host_vars/` folder such as `$PLAYBOOK_DIR/host_vars/somehostname.yml`

See [Ansible doc on variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

You may also want to check out [Directory Layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) and [Alternative Directory Layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) for a better understand regarding all these directories and files.

Comment: where is the no. for inventory extra parameters ?

Comment: What do you mean "inventory extra parameters"? Inventory vars are between 3 and 9

Comment: I meant assigning variable at hosts level. check this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables